# Watching order for Lost, incorporating mini-episodes

Tags: suggested-order, lost

Where should additional episodes and so on be watched, when watching Lost seasons 1-6 in the normal order (not rearranged chronologically for instance)? How should they be interleaved with the regular episodes?

Answer (score 3):

**The best way to view the media is probably in release order.**

This should minimize spoilers, and any spoilers you do get will at least be the ones the writers intended.

- *Lost: Season 1*
- *Lost: Season 2*, episodes 1–5
- *Endangered Species*

  This was released on November 1, 2005, several days before the sixth episode of Season 2.
- *Lost: Season 2*, episodes 6–9
- *Secret Identity*

  This was published on January 6, 2006. The 10th episode aired five days later.
- *Lost: Season 2*, episodes 10–14
- *Signs of Life*

  This novel was published on March 1, 2006. This was the same day as the 15th episode of Season 2, so one can read them in whatever order one prefers. Probably one should watch the episode first.
- *Lost: Season 2*, episodes 15–19
- *The Lost Experience*

  This game had different release dates in different countries. It was first released in the UK on May 2, 2006, so presumably does not contain any spoilers for episodes later than 2x19.
- *Lost: Season 2*, episodes 20–24
- *Lost: Season 3*
- *Lost: Missing Pieces* (1–9)

  The first of these mobisodes aired in the fall of 2007, and the last aired January 28, 2008, shortly before the beginning of the fourth season.
- *Find 815*

  This ARG started on December 31, 2007, so you might want to play it here. On the other hand, it finished shortly before the beginning of Season 4, so it might be worth playing after *all* the episodes of *Missing Pieces*.
- *Lost: Missing Pieces* (10–13)
- *Lost: Season 4*, episodes 1–4
- *Lost: Via Domus*

  This was released on February 28, 2008, on the same day as the fifth episode of Season 4.
- *Lost: Season 4*, episodes 4–10
- *Bad Twin*

  This is a book that is present within the fictional narrative of *Lost*. It was published on May 2, 2008, the day after Season 4, Episode 10.
- *Lost: Season 4*, episodes 10–14
- *Dharma Initiative Recruiting Project*
- *Lost: Season 5*
- *Lost University*

  This content was on the Blu-rays for the fifth season, so that's all you need to have watched.
- *Mysteries of the Universe* (episode 1)

  These featurettes were released in five parts. The first was released on July 24, 2009, and the last was released on November 16. Thus they were all released before the air date of the final season (February 2, 2010).
- *Damon, Carlton, and a Polar Bear*

  This was released on July 25, so should be watched after the first *Mysteries of the Universe* episode. It probably does not matter much, though.
- *Mysteries of the Universe* (episodes 2–)
- *Lost: Season 6*
- *The New Man in Charge*

  This is basically an epilogue. It was released in August 2010, after the end of the final season, and clears up some loose ends.
- *The Lost Encyclopedia*

  Read this last. Since it was released in October 2010, after the show had concluded, it is absolutely full of spoilers for the regular episodes.

<sub>The *chronological* ordering of several of the works is [here](http://www.alltimelines.com/lost/). Also, a list of *Lost* media can be found [here](http://%3Csub%3EThe%20basic%20ordering%20of%20several%20of%20the%20works%20is%20[here][1].%3C/sub%3E).</sub>